# How to force DotNetCore 2.1 Web API to output Json format? What library do I need?

Tags: json, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I be straight to the point. I am in the process of converting ASP.Net web services into  DotNetCore 2.1 services. My question is very simple. How do I get json output from a string (with a GET verb)?
I'm new at this, but almost every piece of documentation and recommendations do not work with DotNetCore.

Obviously, the following will not work:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    return "{\"country_code\":\"US\",\"country_name\":\"United States\",\"region_name\":\"California\",\"city_name\":\"Los Angeles\",\"latitude\":\"34.052230\",\"longitude\":\" - 118.243680\",\"zip_code\":\"90001\",\"time_zone\":\" - 08:00\"}";
}
```

I just need to convert this string (or tell the client) that I want the output in json. The following does not work either - got a squiggly line under the "Json(" method and, for the life of me, can't find a reference to make it go away (I pulled it from an example, so they must be using a 3rd party json parsing library or there's a reference that I'm missing)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json("{\"country_code\":\"US\",\"country_name\":\"United States\",\"region_name\":\"California\",\"city_name\":\"Los Angeles\",\"latitude\":\"34.052230\",\"longitude\":\" - 118.243680\",\"zip_code\":\"90001\",\"time_zone\":\" - 08:00\"}", "application/json"); 
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to serialize an object to json, but figured I'd start with something ridiculously simple. 
Anywho, if anyone can help.

Comment: Try Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: If you use the Visual Studio's project templates it should be configured by default to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already have a strongly typed model, you can build an anonymous type and return that from the controller

Simple Example.

```
public class MyController: Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        var model = new {
            country_code = "US",
            country_name = "United States",
            region_name = "California",
            city_name = "Los Angeles",
            latitude = 34.052230,
            longitude = -118.243680,
            zip_code = 90001,
            time_zone = "- 08:00"
        };
        return Ok(model); //200 OK with content
    }    
}
```

In more complex scenarios you would get your objects from a data source.

No library needed, the framework out of the box will serialize the object(s) into JSON for you by default unless otherwise configured.

If you insist on passing a manually formatted string then use the [`ContemntResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) object. Pass it the string and the content type.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
    string json = "{\"country_code\":\"US\",\"country_name\":\"United States\",\"region_name\":\"California\",\"city_name\":\"Los Angeles\",\"latitude\":\"34.052230\",\"longitude\":\" - 118.243680\",\"zip_code\":\"90001\",\"time_zone\":\" - 08:00\"}";
    return Content(json, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

Reference [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

> #### Forcing a Particular Format
>
> If you would like to restrict the response formats for a specific action you can apply the
>   `[Produces]` filter. The `[Produces]` filter specifies the response
>   formats for a specific action (or controller). Like most Filters, this
>   can be applied at the action, controller, or global scope.
>
> ```
> [Produces("application/json")]
> public class AuthorsController
> ```
>
> The `[Produces]` filter will force all actions within the
>   `AuthorsController` to return JSON-formatted responses, even if other
>   formatters were configured for the application and the client provided
>   an Accept header requesting a different, available format.

Comment: IActionResult was where I went wrong. This worked perfectly in PostMan. Thanks for the detailed answer and working example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return string but object. So result of your actions are json string this is why you will get string in JSON and not an object

Make sure that your client is sending header "Content-Type": "application/json".

```
[HttpGet]
public Address Get()
{
    return new Address{ CountryCode = "US"} ; 
}
```